# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4fa2b3f1 when doing CStatic.Create

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, exception, access-violation

I have problem with CStatic. So I have this:

```
    CStatic * lblPresent;
    SetWindowPos(NULL,GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)/2-234,0,0,0,SWP_NOSIZE | SWP_NOZORDER);
    lblPresent=new CStatic();
    wstring wtemp=L"Welcome";
    tempChar = new WCHAR[wtemp.length()+1];
    wcscpy_s(tempChar, wtemp.size()+1, (LPWSTR)wtemp.c_str());
    lblPresent->Create(tempChar, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,CRect(20, 90, 448, 130), this);
```

When it reach that last line, it says:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x6e54ba20 in CPTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x4fa2b3f1.
```

When I step over using debugger, it brings me to this:

```
AfxWndProcDllStatic(HWND hWnd, UINT nMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    AFX_MANAGE_STATE(&afxModuleState);
    return AfxWndProc(hWnd, nMsg, wParam, lParam);
}
```

The exception seems to happen in that line that returns, with the values (written in the watch):

```
        hWnd    0x001a01d0 {unused=0 }  HWND__ *
        lParam  0                       long
        nMsg    272                     unsigned int
        wParam  2425038                 unsigned int
```

Does anyone know what happens and what to do?

Thanks,
Reinardus

Comment: What is the full callstack at the time of the exception?

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you make it this simple:

```
lblPresent->Create(L"Welcome", WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,CRect(20, 90, 448, 130), this);
```

Is `this` pointer valid and actually pointing to some valid CWnd ?